# Tikz patterns library and dvisvgm4ht

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, make4ht, dvisvgm

Does the `dvisvgm4ht` driver with `make4ht` support the TikZ Patterns library? The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\begin{document}
    Testing patterns:
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[pattern = north east lines] (-1,2) rectangle (-2,-2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

generates the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xml:lang='en-US' lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Test2.css' /> 
<meta content='Test2.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' id='MathJax-script'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 6 --><p class='noindent'>Testing patterns:
</p><!-- l. 8 --><p class='indent'>   <img src='Test20x.svg' alt='  ' />
</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

and an empty SVG file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

I've updated the [`dvisvgm4ht`](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht) driver. It is possible to choose between `dvips` (default) and `dvisvgm` backend. The `dvisvgm` backend supports TikZ patterns, but it fails with some complex pictures, so it isn't used by default. To select it, use the `tikz+` option:

```
make4ht -m draft filename.tex "tikz+"
```

Original answer:

The `dvisvgm4ht` driver uses another driver, `pgfsys-dvips.def`, internally. It seems that it doesn't support patterns. It doesn't use `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def`, because it didn't record the image dimensions correctly, they were set to zero. So even if the SVG file contained the graphics, it couldn't be displayed.

I finally found the way how to correctly use the `dvisvgm` driver and keep the image dimensions. Here is a new version of `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def`:

```
% Copyright 2020 by Michal Hoftich
% Copyright 2006 by Till Tantau
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/generic/pgf/licenses/LICENSE for more details.

\ProvidesFileRCS{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}

% Driver commands for tex4ht

%
% Load common pdf commands:
%
\input pgfsys-dvisvgm.def
%\input pgfsys-dvips.def


\def\texfourht@tikz@begin{%
  \bgroup%
  \ifdefined\inside@pict@cmd% handle nested uses
  \def\run@pict@cmd{}% insert the \Picture hooks only in the top nesting level
  \def\end@pict@cmd{}%
  \else
  % use different version of \Picture depending on the vertical mode
  \ifvmode\def\run@pict@cmd{\Picture*}\else\def\run@pict@cmd{\Picture+}\fi%
  \def\end@pict@cmd{\EndPicture}%
  \fi%
  % command used to detect nesting
  \def\inside@pict@cmd{}%
  \csname a:tikzpicture\endcsname%
}

\def\texfourht@tikz@end{%
  \csname b:tikzpicture\endcsname%
  \egroup%
  \par%
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  % configure the output picture format to svg
  \Configure{Picture}{.svg}
  % insert tex4ht hook to the code used at the start and end of each TikZ picture
  \def\pgfsys@beginpicture{%
    \texfourht@tikz@begin%
    \orig@pgfsys@begin%
  }%
  \def\pgfsys@endpicture{%
    \orig@pgfsys@end%
    \texfourht@tikz@end%
  }%
}


% Make the code inserted by tex4ht configurable

\NewConfigure{tikzpicture}{2}
\Configure{tikzpicture}{%
  % \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%\HtmlParOff
  \protect\csname nested:math\endcsname% support display math
  \run@pict@cmd{}%
}{\end@pict@cmd}

\let\orig@pgfsys@begin\pgfsys@beginpicture
\let\orig@pgfsys@end\pgfsys@endpicture
\def\pgf@sys@postscript@header#1{{\special{! #1}}}

\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/before}{\texfourht@tikz@begin}
\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/after}{\texfourht@tikz@end}

\endinput


%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% End:
```

The difference to the original driver is that it now patches directly the `tikzpicture` environment, instead of just patching of internal TikZ driver macros:

```
\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/before}{\texfourht@tikz@begin}
\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/after}{\texfourht@tikz@end}
```

Downside is that it won't work for the `\tikz` command.

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, I am unable to get it to work, though. I modified the driver file and now I get this error message:


`[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of Test2.html failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: ...Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/body) [char=743]`


when I run `make4ht Test.tex "xhtml,mathjax"`

Comment: Edit: The above was with a single line of text "Testing Patterns" added to the MWE right before the tikz picture.

Comment: @Rushi can you please update your question with the code that fails? I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Added the code, the html, the SVG, and an image of the rendered webpage.

Comment: @Rushi ah I see. You need to put `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}` before `\usepackage{tikz}`, because it has no effect when you put it after that.

Comment:  I will revert the question to it's original form and accept your answer so other readers are not confused. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is worth submitting a feature request to the dvisvgm developer M. Gieseking to add support for PostScript patterns.

Comment: @AlexG the problem is not in dvisvgm, but in the dvisvgm4ht driver. The `pgfsys-dvips` driver works for this sample.

Comment: But It seems that dvisvgm does not support PostScript patterns. For testing, I used the code from the first code box of the question and deleted the line with the driver setting.

Comment: @AlexG you are right. I thought that it worked, but I cannot reproduce it now.